# Don't display a button while file exists on server

Tags: php, html, css, display, file-exists

I'm trying to display a download button on an HTML page only when a specific file on the web server is deleted. I thought I'd use a CSS `display: none;` then a PHP script with a while loop that'd look like this :

```
while (file_exists("/aaa/file.txt")) {
      sleep(5);
    }
//set display property of the invisibleLink class to block and continue
```

The thing is I don't know how to do this last step and every thread I've seen about modifying CSS with PHP doesn't work with my use case.

Comment: That's because your PHP is executed at your server, and the CSS is rendered by the client.

Comment: putting a sleep in just delays the response to the client by that amount of time. This makes no sense. If the file is never deleted then your page will never get a response and will time out. What you should do is, if the file exists at the time of the request, show the button. If not, don't show it. If the user presses the button, check the status of the file again. If it's been deleted in the time between the button being rendered and the request coming back from the user, just return an error or warning, whatever is appropriate for your use case.

Comment: You could do an ajax call to a server side script that tells you if the file exists or not and then add / remove a class based on the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP executes before anything is displayed on the screen, so you are probably not going to be able to do that: the code would simply sleep for 5 and then continue with generating the rest of the html before displaying to the user.

What you might want to do instead is mark the button as display: none and then when the page is done loading have a js function that calls a php page that returns whether the file exists or not. Have the js function loop until the php page says the file is gone, then have the js function display the button and stop looping.

```
<button type="button" id="test_btn" style="display: none;">Download</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        checkFile();

        function checkFile() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/path/to/file_checker.php',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data === "deleted") { // or whatever you want the response to be
                        $('#test_btn').show();
                    }
                    else {
                        checkFile(); // you can add a setTimeout if you don't want this running too often
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then your file checker php can be something similar to what you had:

```
if (file_exists("/aaa/file.txt")) {
    echo "exists";
}
else {
    echo "deleted";
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Working perfectly, thanks ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just build the button and hide it with a class like this:

```
<style>
.hidden{ display:none;}
</style>

<?php
if(!file_exists("path") ){ $class = "hidden" }
  echo "<input type='button' class='$class' name='stuff'>woo</button>";
?>
```

Comment: Why not just `if( file_exists("path") ){ echo "<input type='button' class='$class' name='stuff'>woo</button>";}`?

Comment: No need for a class if you do it that way, but that's another way yeah. But with PHP, there's 50 ways to do one thing.