# Show and Hide Button (href=) if file exist in server or not

Tags: php, css, display

I tried editing a similar solution but it doesnt do what it was intended to. Im not sure about my coding maybe im wrong and im using html. Is there a way to hide button(href=) if file exists then show if its not found? thank you!

ref: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941277/dont-display-a-button-while-file-exists-on-server)

```
<button type="button" id="test_btn" style="display: none;">Download</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        checkFile();

        function checkFile() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/path/to/file_checker.php',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data === "deleted") { 
                        $('#test_btn').show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#test_btn').hidden();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then your file checker php can be something similar to what you had:

```
if (file_exists("/aaa/file.txt")) {
    echo "exists";
}
else {
    echo "deleted";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
              crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>
```

Add CSS class to your button and include jquery in your page

```
.hidden {
display: none
}
```

then

```
<button type="button" class="hidden" id="test_btn">Download</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                url: '/path/to/file_checker.php',
                type: 'GET',
                success:function(data){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                           if(obj.callback == 1) {
                             $('button#test_btn').removeClass('hidden');
                            }
                }
                });
});
</script>
```

In your /path/to/file_checker.php

```
if (file_exists("/aaa/file.txt")) {
    $data = array('callback' => 1);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
else {
    $data = array('callback' => 0);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach would be to offer a list of the files that exist to the user and allow them to select from the list.

```
<?php
// Initialize an empty array
$files = [];

// Get all the files in a directory (this will also return directories)
foreach (glob('*') as $f) {

        // If the item is a file, add it to the files array
        if (is_file($f)) {
                $files[] = $f;
        }
}
?>

<!-- Create a select statement with the files that exist -->
<select id="files">
<!-- Placeholder -->
<option disabled selected>Select file</option>

<!-- Loop through all the files and create options for them -->
<?php foreach ($files as $f) : ?>
<option><?= $f ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>

<!-- The button would run the download using the selected file as the source (additional JavaScript required) -->
<button id="go">Download</button>
```

Comment: wow thats great! i will try and learn how to implement this one. thank you very much!